Bivariate normal distribution to marginal PDF
I am studying abt the bivariate normal distribution and trying to get the normal distribution by integration, and I'm trying to use change of variables and idk why it doesn't work.
$$
\frac{1}{2π_x_y\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}exp(-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}[\frac{(x-_x)^2)}{_x^2} + \frac{(y-_y)^2)}{_y^2} - 2\rho\frac{(x-_x)(y-\mu_y)}{_x\sigma_y}])
$$
So I tried the following transformation:
$$
u = \frac{x-\mu_x}{_x}\\\
v = \frac{y - \mu_x}{\sigma_y}
$$
Therefore I changed the given formula like this:
$$
\int^∞_{-∞} \frac{1}{2π\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}exp(-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}(u - v)^2)du
$$
And I'm not sure how to do the integration :( Can anybody help me?

What you are calculating is really the double integral (whose value is $1$). You have to keep $x$ fixed and integrate w.r.t $y$ to get the first marginal. A two-dimensional change of variable is not what you need.
